# ARRAYFORMULA with COUNT

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

im trying to come up with an ARRAYFORMULA to substitute formulas on every row

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);""; COUNTA(FILTER((Derivatives!B:B);INDEX((Derivatives!D:D);0;0)= left(A2;4);INDEX((Derivatives!F:F);0;0)= "EQUITY CALL")))
```

[Exemple](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjr2J4HA-CY90hoA1Fh0TPQjbPfdrKt3jQbXEI9GZvM/edit#gid=842392593)

example is almost correct, most of 1 results should be 0, i belive thats caused by COUNTA, not sure, bigger numbers should be correct on my exemple

- basicly to COUNT number of times Derivatives!B:B, those are UNIQUE
- WHERE Derivatives!D:D matches LEFT(Example!A2;4),
- AND Derivatives!F:F is EQUITY CALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2:A; 4); 
 QUERY({LEFT(Derivatives!D:D; 4)\ Derivatives!F:F}; 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 ='EQUITY CALL' group by Col1"); 2; 0); 0))
```

[image]